# Retrieving Windows Phone 8 Device Model Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I retrieve the Device model name/number of a windows phone 8 device, like for example,  for a Nokia phone, I would like to retrieve the model e.g **Lumia 925**. How is it possible programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer+" "+DeviceStatus.DeviceName
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you [copy code from somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122013/getting-windows-phone-version-and-device-name-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml), name the source. "Hope this helps" also isn't a good answer, try to link to the docs or something.

Comment: @Vyas_27 not giving me what i want, this was the output for my device "NOKIA RM-910_im_mea3_212" need an output like "Nokia Lumia 925"

Comment: @jade see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425016/information-about-windows-phone-model-number) for that.